# How do I make two wall switches work in coordination, wirelessly?

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, rewire

I remodeled my kitchen and added under cabinet lighting.  The under the cabinet lights are controlled by a wall switch on one side of the kitchen.  The overhead recessed can lights have a switch on the other side of the kitchen.

1) I’d like the overhead light switch to not only turn on the overhead lights but also the under the cabinet lights.  2) I’d like the under the cabinet light switch to only turn on and off the under the under cabinet lights.

How might I do this?  Ideally without having to pull wire (so using wireless switches)?  While I don't want say an additional switch on one wall or the other, I am happy to replace the kind of switch that is in the current switch locations.

I already have a Wink hub, but don't need any kind of timer or even remote on/off from my phone.  These lights are all LED, and I don’t want or need to dim them either.

Answer (score 4):

#### There are half a dozen ways one could do this, but I would do it this way

- Purchase 2 Lutron RF Maestros. ( The RF part is important, as they sell none RF Maestros too) ( for non dimming use MRF2-6ANS )
  [image]
  [image]
- One Pico wireless switch
  [image]
- One Pico switch plate adapter
  [image]
- One 2 gang decor plate
  [image]
- Change both switches to the RF Maestro and put the Pico next to the switch that controls the recessed lights using the Pico adapter and 2 gang wall plate. (No cutting necessary).
- Program the Pico to turn on both RF Maestros and you're done.
- If using electronic or magnetic LED the Maestro will need to be compatible and same goes for the recessed lights.  But since you are not dimming these you do not need to worry about that nor would you need to worry about the wattage.

Comment: This is good.  As I understand it, in your scenario, I add a new PICO remote switch that controls both the recessed lights and the under the cabinet lights.  Is there a way to do this using only the current two physical wall switches?  Both of these switches already have three switches total in their respective locations.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to replace the existing switches as the the Pico talks to the RF Maestros. Replacing the switches should be relatively easy. Just turn power off and replace. One thing though is the Non dimming Maestro **may** require a neutral.

Comment: yes, I expect to replace the switches.  I have neutrals too.  I was hoping that I could avoid adding the additional physical switch on the wall too.  I think that I see what you are suggesting and I am wondering if I can I do this somehow without adding that extra switch (for the PICO remote) on the wall.

Comment: The Pico would just require the switch plate adapter. It is not necessary to cut the wall and make the box bigger.  It can also be used as a handheld remote.

Comment: Okay, great!  I see that I can do this, but it will require another physical switch on my wall (no cutting sheet rock though).  I just don't want to add any more switches to the wall.  Three is enough for each location.

Comment: @DavidC, bad news... Just found out the Maestro low voltage magnetic dimmers don't always work with LED magnetic loads. Possible reason is the minimum load requirement is 40 watts, and is also electronic based dimming verses mechanical. However, most under counter LEDs are electronic, not magnetic in which case you might be okay with a Maestro electronic dimmer. But I just remembered you are not dimming these.  My bad.

Comment: Along the same lines -- you could replace each switch with an Insteon on/off switch -- like [this one](http://www.amazon.com/INSTEON-2477S-SwitchLinc-Dual-Band-Control/dp/B008HUWWOC/ref=cm_cd_al_qh_dp_t).  Link the two switches together with each controlling the other and when you turn either on or off the other will follow.   I have this setup for a hallway with 3 dimmer switches.